# Why cant Java load this class: com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLRSAPublicKey

Tags: java, android, sockets, rsa

currently I am working on a school Project. The goal of this project is to receive data from a Server and writing data to the Server. For this purpose I am using Sockets and ServerSockets. To encrypt the messages I am using Apache Commons Codec 1.9.

(Server is a java .jar file executed on an Ubuntu Server and the client is an android app)

**Server/Client**

To encrypt the messages I am exchanging public keys.

```
private void Schluesselaustausch() {
    try {

        GenerateKeys gk = new GenerateKeys(4069);
        gk.createKeys();
        ServerPrivateKey = gk.getPrivateKey();

        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        oos.writeObject(gk.getPublicKey());
        oos.flush();
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        Object obj = ois.readObject();
        ClientPublicKey = (PublicKey) obj; //Line 108

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The error occurs when an object is casted to an PublicKey (Line 108).

The Client has the same function, but he is receiving and then sending an object.

***The Error***

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLRSAPublicKey
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:374)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:685)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1879)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1765)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2053)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1587)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at Engine.ClientVerbindung.Schluesselaustausch(ClientVerbindung.java:108)
    at Engine.ClientVerbindung.run(ClientVerbindung.java:49)
```

**There is more**

Now to the strange part: Everything works if I am using a client running on PC. So I figured out that my server was coded on Java 10 but on my Ubuntu Server there was Java 11 installed. I downgraded Java and tested it again. Nothing changed.

**My Questions**

Is there an error in Android?
Do I have to upgrade java to 11?
What is the problem?

Thank you for your help.
RT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sending a key (some string or number value) but the whole Java object back and forth through the `Object*Stream`s. When you use a PC you are basically using the same Java implementation as the server, so the server can deserialize this Java object. If you `System.out.println` the `.getClass()` of the received object on the server, you will find that it does not talk about `com.android....`.

Yet, when you connect from your mobile device, the Android Java version is used and it obviously contains Android specific objects of class `com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLRSAPublicKey`. The server does not have these class definitions anywhere in its library, so it cannot deserialize them.

Rather then de-/serializing the Java key objects, you should send the plain keys around.

Comment: You could create a common jar library of custom data classes that both projects include as a dependency - if you want to serialise / deserialise an object type.

Comment: Thank you very much. That makes totally sense.